# Use cache data like a boss

Tags: redis, memcached

- I have a confusion in redis or memcached in which (stutivation or data) want to cache the database record.
- Doing the accounting project it have more then 10k users, while application hit more means my database execution takes more time to response.
- I used the index and query optimization in better.

Can anyone please help me to use the cache like a boss.

Comment: A boss didn't become a boos by reading a SO answer, or even a whole article, it needs a lot of reading, experimentation. You definitely need to cache the rarely changed db results.
I suggest to start reading only on one of those (Redis) to invest time in your learning curve. 
Then, chunkify your question, to get a better answer. Good luck :)

Comment: ok thanks for your time to replay, i understand the concept of cache  so biscally we can cache the long runing logic and settings of application (ex : country, state, etc).